# Create each forum with different custom fields

Tags: nodes

I am using [Advance forums](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) module and I am trying to have each forum with different custom fields. I created a new content type and non-forum taxonomy terms. My question is how to display **taxonomy terms** in forums container since they are not treated as forum vocabulary terms.